# IPhone: Objective C global variables

Tags: objective-c

I know there as various posts regarding global variables in SO, but nothing helped.
My problem is-
In my AppDelegate.h I declared two variables x and y. In my ClassA, I imported AppDelegate.h and added:

```
AppDelegate  mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

and assigned values to `mainDelegate.x` and `mainDelegate.y`.

In ClassB, I assigned these x and y as

```
label1.text = mainDelegate.x;
label2.text = mainDelegate.y;
```

No errors,but it is null..nothing appears as label's text.

Could anyone please help..

EDIT:
In AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *x,*y;
```

In ClassA.m

```
mainDelegate.x=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[homeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

This mainDelegate.x I am trying to get from ClassB and it is null.

Comment: How have you declared x, and y? Are they properties?

Comment: Please provide some code snippets.

Comment: declaration of x and y in AppDelegate.h

'@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString x,y;'

Comment: @dinny Have you written your details down exactly? You should have `AppDelegate *mainDelegate` and `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *x; @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *y;` The asterisks are important, these are pointers we're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *x,*y;
```

and not

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString x,y;
```

By using copy, you are ensuring that the text labels stay consistent. While retain means that if you change the values of x and y somewhere, your text labels will also change.

Comment: Thanks, but then 'copy' didnt help

Comment: Then I need to see your when you are allocating the NSString, it should be @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *x, *y; also. (The added *).

Comment: And you forgot the `*` as well.

Comment: Please add the code where you set the values for x and y and also the @interface of your AppDelegate.

Comment: i have added it to the question

Comment: Also I want to see NSString x,y from the interface, it is `NSString *x,*y;` right? Are you sure that `[homeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` returns an `NSString *`? What happens to the label if you set `mainDelegate.x = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];`. Will the label then display "Hello"?

Comment: mainDelegate.x = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"]; doesnt show Hello!!!

Comment: I need to see more code in order to determine the error. In what class are you setting mainDelegate.x ? and when are you setting it? Maybe after you are setting the label.text?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the outlets to label1 and label2 , what happens if you set label1.text = @"Hello"; ?

Comment: mainDelegate.x = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"]; 

The label doesnt show anything.

 NSLog("%sthe value", mainDelegate.x) shows :-
 ¿?„the value

Comment: @dinny - You're trying to log an NSString, not a c-string. What you should be doing is `NSLog("%@ the value", mainDelegate.x)`

Comment: @Abizern: Thanks,that did work, i mean i could get the value in the label. And it was fault in my side, it should have been

mainDelegate.x=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[homeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.secton]]; and not indexPath.row as i had arranged my table view in that way. 

@ Man of One Way: Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Would setting your x and y variables as static variables help?

```
static int x;
static int y;
```

EDIT:

Actually, I noticed you're assigning a value to a UILabel(?). Have you alloc and init your UILabel before assignment value to it? That's one possible cause of getting null values.

Comment: I gave 
 NSLog(@"%sthe value ",mainDelegate.x);
it showed
 ¿?„the value
in the console

Comment: @dinny - You're trying to log an NSString, not a c-string. What you should be doing is NSLog("%@ the value", mainDelegate.x)

Comment: Could you check: if(label1 == nil) { NSLog(@"label1 is nil"); } and see if it prints out "label1 is nil" ?